# Why bash for loop goes to stopped job when Ctrl+C is pressed?

Tags: bash, less, job-control

Suppose I have a `log` file generated this way:

```
yes | head -n 1000000 > log
```

Now when I view it like this

```
for i in log; do cat $i; done | less -S
```

press Ctrl+C in `less` and quit it with `q`, some unexpected stopped job is created in bash

```
[1]+  Stopped                 for i in log;
do
    cat $i;
done | less -S
```

I expected no stopped jobs after exiting from `less`. How can I avoid it in bash?

Comment: One workaround is not to use Ctrl/C but just `q`

Comment: @roaima, sometimes I need to cancel long running search in `less` with Ctrl/C, so I have to use it.